Meaning of "Ogan"
I have been searching across the internet for the meaning of a word I have come across on a phone case.
What does OGAN mean?


In any case, it's not English.  Some of the other text may be Turkish, per Google translate.

Probably this: The Ogan Foundation's Vision for Digital Education for Kids. https://www.oganfoundation.org/blog/the-ogan-foundations-vision-for-digital-education-for-kids

Follovers seems to be a brand, possibly Ogan is too.

Sinan Oğan?

It's almost certainly nonsense, some non-English-speaking mobile phone case designer copying some letters. Maybe the thing it copied said LOGAN or something else but was cut off. On the other hand you could buy it, use it every day, and see if anyone ever says something.

If the canonical question about the axe on a rubber ball is off topic, this one might be too. But go give it a read if you have some time and like this sort of thing.

In Gothic (an extinct East Germanic language, and was used by Tolkien also), ogan means 'fear, be afraid'. Source: Anatomy of the Verb
The Gothic Verb as a Model for a Unified Theory of Aspect, Actional Types, and Verbal Velocity by Albert L. Lloyd

It's not an English word. Best I can tell, it's an inside joke related to the designer, Connie Dávalos. The Facebook page for Connie's business lists the email "ogan@thevibebox.com".
From Twitter user EKVG_94 via Google Translate:

I get something weird every time I hear Connie Davalos say "ogan"
Me da no sé qué cada que escucho a Connie Davalos decir "ogan"

